# Web app or normal? software to develop this system idea?

Tags: c#, php, html

A friend has asked me to look into developing a custom system for his taxi cab company. Currently they have no system in place at all to handle their accounts or the jobs/booking etc. Eventually there will be extras like mobile applications to book but for now i need to get a backbone system developed.

He is talking about building it all as a web app, so all the accounts information/invoices etc are all in one location (most likely on a secure dedicated server) so that the ppl in the office or himself on his tablet if hes out and about can easily see what is what etc.

Part of me for some reason is not 100% convinced this is the best idea, but it does keep it all in the same place it does mean that if for example i write something in .net it doesnt need to be installed on all the machines and he can access it all from home or his tablet.

Can anyone think or link to a study paper or something, which might suggest which way is the better way to go with this? if its a web app it will most likely be done in php/html5 (i have been learning Django but dont think my skills are all there yet) if not a web app it will most likely be Java or C# (i am in the process of learning c++ but again skills arent all there.)

tldr: C#/Java system or php/html5 web app for a taxi accounts/booking system.

If this is the wrong place to post this sort of question, deepest apologies and close accordingly

Comment: Interesting link, I built an android app last year in uni to book a taxi to come to your location based on gps or internet location tools. This is something which will be integrating into this system in the long run, at the moment its important to get all the data off of paper records and computerised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a desktop dev and in this case it's probably better done in the web.

If we use C#:
we have a server and a conbecting program. c# doesnt work everywhere (though java does) but just for something relatively small like this it's past overkill. but you can have offline data (if its needed though)

web:
easy to access (just need a browser) and light

THIRD OPTION:
C# can be used to develop web applications. as sich you can make it in C# and have it be accessible through a browser. (I would choose this, but I'm a desktop dev so I guess it's normal).

I'll leave you with this, mainly post to show you theres another way.

Comment: I have never used c# to build web apps, how is it? does it not require the .net framework on the target machine? would this be overkill so something easily built in php?

Comment: c# web apps require asp.net on the **server**. it will work pretty much like any other site otherwise. but it will be easier to port to a mobile app etc.

Comment: also, i think its possible to build web apps without asp.net, but that's specifics at this point, you get the main idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a desktop application developer, but I will chip in my opinion. The web has come a long way and it's very easy to make web user interfaces now. The biggest benefit you will probably gain from a web application is it is operating system dependent; anyone with a web browser will be able to use it.

Comment: This is part of the for argument for making it all web based, the only real concern I guess is security of financial data being stored on the web server, i must confess my ignorance on being up-to-date with internet security (maybe this is the done thing now a days) with this in mind does it add something in the con part of doing it all web?

Comment: Don't expect that making 'just' a web application will make it work (properly) on anything with a webbrowser. The usage patterns of a mobile device or tablet are vastly different from someone using the system with a mouse and a keyboard. However, the web is a nice option.
About the safety of financial information... Do you need that on your publicly facing frontends? I would say that you don't really use that on your mobile devices, so you could keep that separate from the public API.

Comment: web security doesn't exist. it's only possible to make it very impractical to get the data. same goes for a program connecting to a server.

Comment: @ErikvanBrakel Yeah ofc, at the moment it is very much getting something down on paper design stage. and due to the direct nature of the system i am able to pin point the users and the systems using it, basically- in office windows based machines running FF or Chrome, the table i know for a fact is a galaxy tab running ICS, there is another partner with an Ipad but i dont think hes planning on using it much

Answer (score 0):

My opinion,

I would have set up a server in Java/C# etc with a restservice or something similar, that way you can easily combine both web and desktop applications. Get the best of both worlds :)